# Reorder and select subset from dataframe based on other dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, the first is the base and the second a subset. I want the base to dictate the sorting for the subset.

```
unit1 = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Alice", "Bob", "Carol"]
unit2 = ["Harry", "Alice", "Tom", "Carol"]
count1 = [6000, 5554, 4346, 3848, 2210, 1112]
count2 = [300, 25, 534, 8480]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(count1, index=unit1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(count2, index=unit2)

dict_of_ward_totals = {}
for row in zip(df1.index, df1[0]):
    t1 = [df2[df2.index.isin([row[0]])]]
    if not t1[0].empty:
        dict_of_ward_totals.update({row[0] : int(t1[0].values)})
stake_month = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_of_ward_totals, orient='index')
```

My goal is to have df2 sorted to Tom, Harry, Alice, Carol

The above attempt tries to go through DF1 and then create a new dataframe using the resulting dict, it doesn't work as it gives my the indexed values for DF2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [132]: df2.loc[df1[0].argsort().index].dropna()
Out[132]:
            0
Tom     534.0
Harry   300.0
Alice    25.0
Carol  8480.0
```

Should do it. `argsort` will return the positions that would sort `df1`.

```
In [133]: df1[0].argsort()
Out[133]:
Tom      5
Dick     4
Harry    3
Alice    2
Bob      1
Carol    0
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

We use index from that to slice `df2`. That introduces NaNs, which we drop.

Comment: Spot on that works like a charm. I'm still stuck in my assembler days and don't see the power of all of the packages. My code is getting smaller and smaller, thanks @TomAugspurger for the help.